# Does chronoboosting the solar forge improve energy regeneration in Starcraft after patch 3.3?

Tags: starcraft-2

The Starcraft 2 - 3.3 patch notes mentioned something - does chronoboosting the solar forge in coop still speed up energy generation?

Comment: It should, only Chrono Wave was nerfed. I didn't play since, though, so can't verify.